# How to format date in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How to format date in Linq
    --------------------------

```
Hi,
I am working on a linq query. I want to format date column to 'Mm/dd/yy' format. But, the Linq query shows error that Linq doesn't support formatting. Any help?
```

Here is my code:

This is part of linq query.I am tring to format and concatinate two columns.

```
select new abc
                           {
                               cardDates = (cad.Key.SchStartDT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "-" + cad.Key.SchEndDT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                           });
```

Comment: Could you show the code what you had written?

Comment: Please show your failing code. More often than not it is much easier to explain a fix to an existing solution than to explain a solution built from scratch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [format date in linq query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778672/format-date-in-linq-query-result)

Comment: select new abc
                       {
                           cardDates = (cad.Key.SchStartDT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "-" + cad.Key.SchEndDT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                       });

Comment: @FoggyDay No,It is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for (LINQ to Objects case)

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var people = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person
            {
               Id = 1,
               Name = "James",
               DateOfBirth = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-25),
            },

            new Person
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "John",
                DateOfBirth = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-20),
            },

            new Person
            {
               Id = 3,
               Name = "Peter",
               DateOfBirth = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-15),
            }
       };

       var result = people.Select(t => new
       {
           t.Name,
           DateStr = t.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
       }).Take(2).ToList();

       foreach (var r in result)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(r.Name);
          Console.WriteLine(r.DateStr);
       }

       Console.ReadLine();
}
```

For Linq to Entities case,  check this answer
[Formatting date in Linq-to-Entities query causes exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839388/formatting-date-in-linq-to-entities-query-causes-exception)

Comment: plz check my code select new abc
                       {
                           cardDates = (cad.Key.SchStartDT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "-" + cad.Key.SchEndDT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                       });

Comment: Is this select from LINQ to Entities (like Entity Framework) or LINQ to Objects (in Memory) ?

Comment: i got an error: : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: oh sorry. I am using LINQ to Entities

Comment: Follow the link that I've updated the answer with.